# Can't find cause of infinite loop

Tags: java, loops

My code is causing an infinite loop, I just can't find where and it's driving me insane. Any help on this? It's gotta be in one of the three methods below. It involves one linked-list. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

```
 public boolean checkNotSamePlacements() {

    Link current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        Link current2 = head;

        while (current2 != null) {

            if (current != current2) {

                if (current.piece.col == current2.piece.col && current.piece.row == current2.piece.row) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
            current2 = current2.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }

    return false;
}


public void checkAttacking () {
    boolean foundPieces = false;
    Link current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        Link current2 = head;
        while (current2 != null) {

            if (current != current2) {

                if ((current.piece.isAttacking(current2.piece)) && foundPieces == false) {

                    System.out.print(current.piece.pieceType + " " + current.piece.col +
                    " " + current.piece.row + " " + current2.piece.pieceType +
                    " " + current2.piece.col + " " + current2.piece.row);
                    foundPieces = true;
                }
            }
            current2 = current2.next;
        }
        current = current.next;
    }
    if (foundPieces == false) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}

public void checkSpotFound (int col, int row) {

    boolean foundPiece = false;
    Link current = head;

    while (current != null) {

        if (current.piece.col == col && current.piece.row == row) {

            System.out.print(current.piece.pieceType);

            foundPiece = true;
        }
    }

    if (foundPiece == false) {
        System.out.print("-");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with your debugger?

Comment: In `checkSpotFound` you never update `current`; where you loop on `current != null`. Thus infinite loop.

Comment: My professors haven't taught us how to use debuggers.. yet hopefully.

Comment: That's a shame, because using a debugger is a very important skill for a programmer.  In fact, throughout the course of a programming career, good use of a debugger can save you literally years of your time.  In this particular case, a debugger would have enabled you to find your problem almost instantly.  Therefore, I strongly recommend that you teach yourself how to use a debugger, as soon as you possibly can.  The effort that you spend on this will pay for itself in no time at all.  Don't wait for your professor to get round to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `current` in your code is never updated -

```
while (current != null) {

    if (current.piece.col == col && current.piece.row == row) {

        System.out.print(current.piece.pieceType);

        foundPiece = true;
    }

    current = current.next; // you might want to add this to your code
}
```

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer123 - if that solves the problem, please be kind to mark this as an answer.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer123 You should see a greyed-out checkmark under the answer's score. Once the questions is 10 mins old, you can click the checkmark to mark it as the answer.